# Magento 2: How do I get current language of store view code?

Tags: magento2, magento2.1

I'm trying to show a custom block for each store view / language.
Therefore I want to create switch statement like:

```
$lang = // Get language code or store view code here;
switch ($lang) {

    case 'en':
        // English block
        break;

    case 'nl':
        // Dutch block
        break;

    default:
        // Dutch block
        break;
}
```

How can I get this? I need it in this file `\app\design\frontend\Venustheme\floristy\Ves_Themesettings\templates\header\default.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

Use `\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` in  `__construct()` of your Block class corresponding to your template file.

Example:

```
/**@var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface **/
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $store,
  .....
) {
  $this->_store = $store;
} 

public function getLocaleCode()
{
    return $this->_store->getLocaleCode();
}
```

Call `getLocaleCode()` function from template file using `$block->getLocaleCode()` which should return something like `en_EN`.